# How do you keep html5 audio playing after iPhone sleeps/locks?

Tags: xcode, html, audio

I have made an app in Xcode that uses web views and plays audio from javascript controlled html5 tags. The audio plays fine but stops as soon as the phone goes to sleep/locks. Is there a simple plist edit that will allow html5 to continue after sleep/lock? Thanks!

Comment: you can't, you can use only built in player to do that - otherwise it would be too easy for app developers to kill the battery by irresponsible or even intentional misuse of the feature